# HttpsURLConnections Default Hostname Verifier

Tags: java, https

I'm using a `HttpURLConnection` in order create a POST request (for fetching a token at some OAuth2 token endpoint). The token endpoint uses HTTPS. I wonder how the hostname verification with regards to HTTPS works. The default hostname verifier of `HttpsURLConnection` seems to be the following [1]:

```
     /**
     * HostnameVerifier provides a callback mechanism so that
     * implementers of this interface can supply a policy for
     * handling the case where the host to connect to and
     * the server name from the certificate mismatch.
     *
     * The default implementation will deny such connections.
     */
    private static HostnameVerifier defaultHostnameVerifier =
        new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String urlHostname, String certHostname) {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

I expected my POST request to fail as this verifier always returns `false`. This is not the case. The comment already states that there is some kind of callback mechanism. What I do not know is: Does the `defaultHostnameVerifier` verify the hostname of the connection and the certificate or is it rather a dummy implementation?

My current coding looks like the following piece:

```
private HttpURLConnection openConnection(String url) throws IOException {
    URL urly = new URL(url);
    final HttpURLConnection con;
    Proxy proxy = getProxy();
    if (proxy == null) {
        con = (HttpURLConnection) urly.openConnection();
    } else {
        con = (HttpURLConnection) urly.openConnection(proxy);
    }

    if (con instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {
        HostnameVerifier verifier = ((HttpsURLConnection) con).getHostnameVerifier(); // there is a default set
        System.out.println(verifier.getClass().getName());
        
    }
    return con;
}
```

I've found some explanation with regards to the `AsyncHttpClient` [2]. As I do not use it at this point of time am I safe going with the default implementation?

[1] https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/com/sun/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.java#L76

[2] https://kevinlocke.name/bits/2012/10/03/ssl-certificate-verification-in-dispatch-and-asynchttpclient/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments at the top say, that class is no longer used; it was the abstract user-visible class that is now replaced by [javax.net.HttpsURLConnection](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.java) which you will observe has the same code. But the *implementation* class for https URL is [sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) which just wraps (delegates to) [sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/https/DelegateHttpsURLConnection.java) which subclasses [sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/https/AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java) which to make the actual connection uses [sun.net.www.protocol.HttpsClient and in particular .afterConnect()](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsClient.java#L426). As background, in earlier versions of Java `SSLSocket` did not do hostname verification, so the implementation of HttpsURLConnection had to add it. In Java 7 up, `SSLSocket` does support 'endpoint identification', so when afterConnect() recognizes that the hostnameVerifier on this URLconnection was the default one, it turns off `needToCheckSpoofing` and sets the `SSLSocket` to do endpoint identification.

[javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.java) is similarly an abstract class that is actually implemented by [sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.java) and several dozen related classes including [sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate()](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/ClientHandshaker.java#L1297) which calls the configurable trustmanager which by default is [sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509TrustManagerImpl.java) which in [checkTrusted()](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509TrustManagerImpl.java#L250) since endpoint identification was requested calls [checkIdentity()](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509TrustManagerImpl.java#L337) which calls [sun.security.util.HostnameChecker](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/util/HostnameChecker.java) with TYPE_TLS (actually meaning HTTPS RFC 2818), and *that* does the actual checking.

Glad you asked?

PS: the analysis on that webpage, that HttpsURLConnection.DefaultHostnameVerifier is called only for mismatch, is quite wrong. As above it is bypassed and *never* called by the actual implementation.

Also I assume you realize java 7 has not been supported for years unless you pay. Although *this* area hasn't changed that I know of in more recent versions. Java 11 does add a new java.net.http.HttpClient which functionally supersedes [Http,Https]URLConnection.